# How to query ambiguous data types in Athena?

Tags: presto, amazon-athena

I have a data set stored in Parquet files crawled from S3 and registered in Glue Data Catalog. Some of the columns are of ambiguous type.

For example column `col` is typed as `struct<long:bigint,string:string>`.

If I select from that table `tbl`, then values of `col` are displayed for example like this:

```
{long=16, string=null}
{long=null, string=15.2}
```

What I would like to do now is query specifically those rows where `col` was classified as a `string`.

How would I do that?

(What would a query have to look like for filtering rows from `tbl` whose value in the `col` column is classified as `long` and `> 10`?)

Comment: Did you try `... WHERE col.long > 10`? How does this differ from your expected results? Also, if you want to filter on `col.string` you can do this: `... WHERE try(CAST(col.string AS bigint)) > 10`.

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen: yes, that works. thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks @Raffael. I am turning this into an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can filter numeric values like this:

```
... WHERE col.long > 10
```

You can filter string values that are actually numbers using Presto [`try`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/conditional.html#try) function, like this:

```
... WHERE try(CAST(col.string AS bigint)) > 10
```